# Connecting to MongoDB using Mongoose in multiple files

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, webpack, react-redux

I'm new to using mongoose and MongoDB. I'm developing a React-Redux app for saving Todo lists. I'm using webpack to bundle everything.

What is the best way to connect to my MongoDB in multiple files? For example, when my initial app.jsx runs, and then in my reducers.jsx file to save to the database...

I know that mongoose maintains a persistent connection, but whenever I try to use

`var mongoose = require('mongoose');`

I get this webpack error

`WARNING in ./~/mongoose/lib/drivers/index.js
Critical dependencies:
8:11-74 the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./~/mongoose/lib/drivers/index.js 8:11-74`

When i create a separate test app, I can successfully write to MongoDB using

`mongoose.connect() and the .save() methods,` when everything is kept in one file.

Thanks

App.jsx

```js
var React = require ('react');
var ReactDOM = require ('react-dom');
var {Route, Router, IndexRoute, hashHistory} = require ('react-router');

var {Provider} = require('react-redux');

var TodoApp = require('TodoApp');

var actions = require('actions');
var store = require('configureStore').configure();
var TodoAPI = require('TodoAPI');


// Connect to MongoDB using mongoose
var url = 'mongodb://joe:test@ds147487.mlab.com:47487/reacttodo';
var mongoose =require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(url);


store.subscribe(()=>{
  var state = store.getState();
  console.log('new state',state);
  TodoAPI.setTodos(state.todos);
});

var initialTodos = TodoAPI.getTodos();
store.dispatch(actions.addTodos(initialTodos));

// load foundation
$(document).foundation();

//app css
require('style!css!sass!AppStyles');

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <TodoApp/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I might be wrong here, but I didn't understand why you are trying to connect to mongodb using a frontend framework?

Comment: How else would I connect?

Comment: You should be doing this on the server side in node/express

Comment: So my initial `connect()` should be in server.js then?

Comment: Yea generally its called in the `app.js` file or some other file you use for init

Comment: See edit above, this is my app.jsx file, and the mongoose calls fails here...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127903/discussion-between-hyades-and-joec).

Answer (score 6):

You need to require `Mongoose` and open a new connection to it in your `server.js` so you can access it through different modules.

Suppose you are using both **express** and **body-parser**

**server.js:**

```
. . .
var mongoose   = require('mongoose');
var port       = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var express    = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
. . .
var app             = express();
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/MyApp");
. . .
app.use(bodyParser.json());
. . .
require('./app/routes.js')(app);
app.listen(port);
console.log('App listening on port ' + port);
```

Then, you can access it easily. Let's suppose you want to set-up a `mongoose schema`.

**mySchema.js:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

var user = new Schema({
          name: {type: String, required : true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', user);
```

Or you just want to retrieve all user or save a new user to the user collection, supposing you are passing it an object `req` which has some properties like name:

**user.factory.js**

```
require('mongoose');
var User = require('mySchema.js');

exports.getUsers = getUsers;
exports.postUser = postUser;

function getUsers() {
  return new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
    var query = User.find({});
    query.exec(function(err, users) {
        if (err){
            return reject({err : 'Error while fetching users'});
        }
        // If no errors are found, it responds with a JSON of all users
        return resolve(users);
     });
  });
}



function postUser(req) {
    return new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
    // Creates a new User based on the Mongoose schema and the post body
      var newUser = new User(req.body);
      // New User is saved in the db.
      newUser.save(function(err) {
          console.log('err',err);
          if (err){
              return reject({err : 'Error while saving new user'});
          }
          // If no errors are found, it responds with a JSON of the new users
          return resolve(req.body);
      });
    });
}
```

Also, suppose you want to set-up a route to intercept `http` requests. For instance, a request to save a new user.

**routes.js:**

```
var UserFactory = require('./factories/user.factory.js');

// Opens App Routes
module.exports = function(app) {

   /** Getting all the users **/
   app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
     UserFactory.getUsers().then( function (users) {
        res.json(users);
     }, function (error) {
        res.json(error);
     });
   });

   /** Posting a new geometry **/
   app.post('/users', function(req, res) {
     UserFactory.postUsers(req).then( function (user) {
        return res.json(user);
     }, function (error) {
        res.json(error);
     });
   });

}
```

And, on the front-end, the user inserts a user name in a form, then clicks on submit button and you call a `createNewUser` function:

```
. . .
var createNewUser = function(userName){

   var user = {
                  name : userName //Goofy
   };

   console.log(user.name); //Goofy

   postNewUser(user).then( function( response, err){
     if(err){
       console.log('Error while saving new user');
     } else {
       console.log('User '+response+' successfully saved');
     }
   });

}

function postNewUser(user){
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
     // Saves user data to the db
     $http.post('/users', user)
          .success(function(res) {
            if(res.error){
               return reject(res.error);
            }
               return resolve(res);
     });
   });
  }
```

You can also set mongoose globally in your **server.js** so you don't need to require it in your modules

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
. . .
global.mongoose = mongoose;
```

Hope I've been helpful.

Comment: Thats really helpful - I got a successful connection in `server.js` but when I try to `require('mongoose')` in your last snippet, I get the webpack error: `WARNING in ./~/mongoose/lib/drivers/index.js
Critical dependencies:
8:11-74 the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./~/mongoose/lib/drivers/index.js 8:11-74`

Comment: That's quite strange. Did you install mongoose through NPM? Do you get this error on `require('mongoose');` line? Set debug on with: `require('mongoose').set('debug', true);`

Comment: Anyways it seems like a dependencies problem with webpack. I could be wrong.

Comment: Yes it must be that line, because when i remove it, webpack runs successfully. Mongoose was installed via npm yeah. set debug didnt make any difference. I'm going to set up a new fresh project and try your example.

Comment: Okay, let me know. I edited my answer for global setting.

Comment: I've got a successful connection, and created the schema and new user as above, but nothing is getting written to my Mongo db. No error is being output either, only a deprecation warning about promises. Cant tell if resolve or reject is being called

Comment: Can you print the request you are passing to the post function?

Comment: yes: `var actions = require('./actions.js');
actions.postUser({
  body:{
    name:'Mongo user Joe test'
  }
});



console.log(actions.getUsers());`

Comment: Outputs this: { name: 'Mongo user Joe test' }

Comment: I try to extend my answer.

Comment: I'm sure that if you understand my edit you'll also understand how to play with mongoose easily, from the front-end to the back-end.